# Why my textclock view dont show second and only minutes and hour

Tags: android-studio

I don't have much experience in android programming. this is my code and idk why it doesn't display the second. I don't have anything yet at the java file.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="This is date"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        />

    <TextClock
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/date"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a "
        android:text="hello"

        android:textSize="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add both android:format12Hour and  android:format24Hour format to your xml and try

```
android:format24Hour="hh:mm:ss"
```

```
    <TextClock
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss a"
        android:format24Hour="hh:mm:ss"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
```